# Normal approximation to a Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, approximation, poisson-distribution

I’m a Maths teacher for IAL Further Maths. One of my students has submitted this response to part d of this exam question. I’m not sure if their solution is acceptable or not. I’d be very grateful if anyone could offer an informed opinion on this.

[image: Student’s work]

[image: Mark scheme - Edexcel IAL S2 January 2015 Q1d]

Comment: This is from the Edexcel IAL S2 January 2015 exam paper.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong; in the second line, the student tries to solve

$$\mathbb P(C \ge x) \cdot 60 \cdot 90 > 5000,$$
when they should compute
$$\mathbb P(C > 5000/60)$$

obtaining the number $5000/60\approx 83.3$ in the mark scheme. I get the impression the student was working backwards from the correct answer; they do happen to give the correct numerical value, but the argument is nonsense.